# Conditional breakpoints and watch window do not short-circuit expression evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**[EDIT - changed example to avoid confusion about the root issue]**

While trying to work out why my conditional breakpoints keep generating errors in Visual Studio, I've stumbled across a behaviour I did not expect.

In the watch window, immediate window, or as the condition of a breakpoint, Visual Studio does not appear to short-circuit expression evaluation.

For example, stopping at a breakpoint on the line after this:

```
string obj = "hello";
```

and evaluating the following in the watch window

```
obj is int && ((int)obj) == 1
```

should give the result

```
false
```

but instead gives

> CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

This prevents me from doing things like checking the type of an object, and then casting to that type and checking a property in my conditional breakpoints, which seriously reduces their usefulness.

Do other people see this behaviour, and does anyone know how to make conditional breakpoints/watch window short-circuit?

The one less-than-ideal workaround that I've come up with is to wrap the expression in a method in your code, and evaluate this from the watch window. However, this involves changing code and recompiling, instead of being able to dynamically change conditions while debugging.

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but does the example fail if you put the second condition in a function in your code? The "division by *constant* zero" is making me suspicious.

Comment: @Rawling - this is just an example to highlight the issue. The lack of short-circuit manifests itself with other code not related to division by zero too. For example obj is string && ((string)obj) == "hello" will fail for a non string with an "unable to cast" error.

Comment: Well it works if the zero is in a variable. This works: `int y = 0; bool asdfg=false && (1 / y == 1);`

Comment: In the immediate window, `false && ((System.Func<bool>)(() => { throw new System.Exception(); }))()` evaluates as false rather than throwing. (Whereas `true && ...` throws.)

Comment: With your second example I think it's the same. In runtime, the compilator knows that `obj`is not a string, so it first try to cast the object before starting to evaluate the conditions...

Comment: @Pikoh Yeah, same again - that's a runtime error so I'm suspicious that it doesn't demonstrate a lack of short-circuiting.

Comment: The point is: there is an issue whereby I cannot do something with a conditional breakpoint that should be simple. 
In a sense, I don't care so much whether it is genuinely a short-circuit problem, or a runtime issue; the issue is that I cannot check a type, and then cast and check a property on it, all within a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: This is a compile time error (hint: CS0030), so runtime discussion is pointless... Write proper code for it! ie `((int)(object)obj)` or make `obj` an `object` like it should be. You cannot cast from `string` to `int`, ever!

Comment: @leppie - I see what you mean. I was taking the error to be suggesting that it was the second condition that was causing the problem (ie when it was trying to do the cast), whereas I now see what you mean: this is a compiler error on the first part of the expression. Thanks.

Comment: @RobLevine: The error is on the 2nd part, first part is just a warning. http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayUAJ0iw+BAFYwAvDABEAC1REifbTlmyCfPkRjzNMFerB1IyGDLNmAZJ5hixLiQcpDS0ARlN2AF9sSKA

Comment: @leppie - sorry - I didn't write _quite_ what I meant. I meant: I was taking the error to be suggesting that the the code was _being evaluated_, and the first part had evaluated but it had, for some reason, moved on to evaluating the second part (which I didn't expect). In fact, it wasn't being evaluated at all - it was not successfully compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this statement wouldn't work in the immediate window or in code either because the compiler knows `obj` will never be castable to `int`.

If you had defined obj as an `object` it would work as expected.

```
object obj = "hello";
bool result = obj is int && ((int)obj) == 1;
```

The code above will compile and work as a breakpoint condition.

As leppie mentioned you could re-cast your object (`(int)(object) obj`) to avoid this, but that should always be a measure of last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to break on a generic property setter with value type `object`

```
(propertyName=="xxx") && (value is int) && ((int)value==5000)
```

Replacing the second && with a ?: operator seems to do the trick

```
(propertyName=="xxx") && ((value is int) ? ((int)value==5000) : false)
```